# Не работает автообновление графика-гистограммы при изменении сводной таблицы

Tags: excel

Есть одна сводная таблица с графиком. Не буду врать, нашел макрос на автоматич обновление графика (любого найденного графика) при изменении сводной таблицы. Макрос я повесил как модуль на первый лист. Но почему-то не работает, пока не нажмешь кнопку запустить. Чувствую я, что подвох в банальном неправильном применении макроса. Подскажите, что я сделал не так?

```
Sub ChartUpdate()
Dim mSheet As Worksheet, mPivot As PivotTable
For Each mSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each mPivot In mSheet.PivotTables
        mPivot.RefreshTable
        mPivot.Update
    Next
Next
MsgBox "File has been refreshed, Charts have been updated"
End Sub
```

Comment: это я потом уберу конечно, но пусть пока будет: MsgBox "File has been refreshed, Charts have been updated"

Comment: Может макрос надо было повесить не как модуль а как код листа?

Comment: Объясните, что Вы поразумеваете под выражениями *"модуль на первый лист"* и  *"код листа"*

Comment: -да, новичок здесь... Имею ввиду прав кноп по Лист1 - Insert- Module

Comment: а может быть проще поступить: WorkSheet - Change

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub   (не могу форматирование здесь)

Comment: ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll тоже не работает. разные версии офиса что ли.